# How to debug just some DLLs of an external program in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I have a program **myProgram.exe** installed in D:\myPrgram\
myProgram.exe uses some dlls which are in the same directory:

myProgram.exe

> - myDll_1.dll
> - myDll_2.dll
> - myDll_3.dll
> - myDll_4.dll

I have a visual studio solution in which I am able to generate only **myDll_1** and **myDll_2**

How can I debug at least **myDll_1** and **myDll_2** generated from my Visual Studio Solution when I run **myProgram.exe**?

- Should I copy my dlls (with .pdb) to the ".exe" directory D:\myPrgram\ ?
- Run myProgram.exe and attach to it from Visual Studio

**Remark :**

- All source code is in C#
- I have **.pdb** of ALL dlls in D:\myPrgram\ : myDll_1, myDll_2, myDll_3 and myDll_4
- I have **.pdb** of **myDll_1** and **myDll_2** generated from my Visual Studio Solution

Comment: If VS finds .pdb files in same folder as .dll - it will load it while debugging. Doesn't matter if you start it from VS or attach to it. When debugging in VS you can open `Modules` and check which modules have their debug symbols loaded. And if some module symbols are not loaded, but you have them you can load them explicitly via context menu on that module.

Comment: @Quercus Thank you. Your answer seems to answer my question but unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve it from the menus of Visual studio

Comment: When debugging, go to 'Debug \ Windows \ Modules'

Comment: @Quercus Thank you. I will try this